# django get original object after values_list

Tags: django

My student model:

```
class Student(Person):
  father = models.ForeignKey('Person', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, 
      null=True,related_name='student_father',help_text=_('Father'))
  mother = models.ForeignKey('Person', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, 
           null=True,related_name=_('student_mother'),help_text=_('Mother'))
  classroom = models.IntegerField(ClassRoom.choices(), null=True, blank=True, 
           help_text=_('Classroom'))
 ..and some other fields
```

I want to get duplicate objects based on 'name','father,'mother' fields.I found duplicate objects with values_list('name','mother','father'),but I can not reach the id of object by this way.If I add id field to values_list method not found duplicate objects.

`Student.objects.values('name', 'father', 'mother').annotate(Count('name')).order_by().filter(name__count__gt=1)`

After this query I need the id of student object.

Comment: What do you mean by "original object" and what is it you are trying to do? plus, please provide some more code for the users to have a background about your code like your models.py

Comment: Couldn't you just add the 'pk' field as a values param?

Comment: If I add 'pk' field,query doesnt work as ı wanted.I want to get duplicate objects according to 'name ' 'father' and 'mother' fields.

Answer (score 1):

What you're attempting to do wouldn't make sense.

You're aggregating a number of records, and then looking for the PK of just one of those aggregated objects.

Consider the scenario that the name "Bill" exists in 8 records. Which PK, for which record, would you expect to be returned?

You'll need to perform a second query, to get the PK of the objects which had duplicate names:

```
names_list = Student.objects.values('name', 'father', 'mother').annotate(Count('name')).order_by().filter(name__count__gt=1)
for names in names_list:
    duplicates = Student.objects.filter(name=names.name)
    for dup in duplicates:
        print dup.pk
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you call `values_list()` or `values()`, you can't get the original object back. `values()` returns [dictionaries, not model instances](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values). However, if you need the primary key, you can just add `pk` to the values list:

```
Student.objects.values('pk', 'name', 'father', 'mother')\
.annotate(Count('name'))\
.order_by()\
.filter(name__count__gt=1)
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice,but if I add the pk field, query doesn't work as I wanted.I want to get duplicate objects acording to only 'name' 'father' and 'mother' fields.